# Access token for liking a post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, access-token

Good day, Im bit confused about this problem. I have a website and i want my facebook PAGE posts to show to my website as well. im using this code in my website to get the posts in facebook:

```
json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?fields=picture,comments,likes,message,admin_creator&access_token=' . $access_token);
```

my problem is

1.) how to embed a like button for these posts in my website that is link directly to my post in facebook? as you can see in my above code i can only get the posts informations and the person who likes my posts.

2.) I want other people to like this posts without going to my facebook page. Below is my like button code it seems to work but i dont know how to obtain a user access token with publish_action permission so that they can like my posts.

Im using this code for the like button:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.api(
    "/post_id/likes?access_token=CAACEdE...... {This access token is obtain using the graph api explorer}",
    "POST",
    function(response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
       console.log(response);
      }
    }
);};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your code and provide as much relevant information as possible to have the highest chance of getting an answer? Check out this resource as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1) Not possible, you can only use the Like Button for external Links or Facebook Pages, but not for specific elements on Facebook.

2) About how to login (which means, get a User Token), please read the following links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/